# Craft CMS License

Tags: license

I want to build a social platform using Craft. The application will be built, hosted and managed by me. Will I need to upgrade the Craft license to Client or Pro before launching the website, or can I run it with Craft Personal ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to test the creation of user accounts without upgrading to Craft Pro. However, in development, you can run Craft Pro as a trial.

From https://craftcms.com/pricing

> Is there a way I can try Craft Client or Pro out before buying?
>
> Yes. As long as you’re running Craft CMS from a non-public-looking
>   domain name (e.g. “mysite.dev” or “staging.mysite.com”), you will have
>   the option to test the Client and Pro editions indefinitely.